# create an array via loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I need to create an array of strings, easy enough... the only problem is that the strings are integers from 1-1000 and I really dont want to type each of them.

Can you create a loop that could create this?

right now it looks like this

```
        private readonly string[] _myArray = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

and its called by

```
        for (var i = 0; i < _myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            arFoo[i].SetBar(_myArray[i]);
        }
```

any suggestions on how to add the other 995 without manually typing them?

Comment: Are you generating random integers?  Could you simply use the C# Random library to generate 1000 ints, convert them to strings, and then run the for loop?

Comment: I do not know if the readonly feature is important to you, but if it is, I see a lot of noise on the answers, as many of them disregard this detail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simple and clean:

```
readonly string[] _myArray 
    = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
        .Select(i => i.ToString())
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Do You know how it compares in performance to 'normal' way of doing it - in for loop?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use LINQ:

```
    private readonly string[] _myArray;

    public Foo()
    {
        _myArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();
    }
```

Or more traditionally:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly string[] _myArray;

    public Foo()
    {
        _myArray = new string[1000];
        for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
        {
            _myArray[i - 1] = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_myArray = new string[1000];
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) _myArray[i - 1] = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr = new string[1000];
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    arr[i-1] = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `arr[i]` should be `arr[i-1]`

Comment: Just change new int[1000] to new string[1000], and array indexes start from 0.

Comment: `string[] arr = new int[1000];` doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Peri @vcsjones Originally I had read the question wrong and assumed it was integers he had wanted..I guess I must've missed out some parts when changing it. And the array indices were from a previous edit I missed.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
int NumberOfElements = 1000;
String[] Array = new String[NumberOfElements];

for(int i=0; i<Array.Length; i++)
{
   Array[i] = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yours will do 0-999, not 1-1000.

Comment: Unless he needs the array to contain 1 in the first element. If so, this would probably work a little better: for(int i = 1; i<=NumberOfElements; i++ )

Answer (score 2):

Do you need an array? You could just do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)       
{            
   arFoo[i].SetBar(i.ToString()); 
}
```

If you do need an array, understand that arrays in C# (and in .Net) are fixed-size. You would need another data structure, like a `List<String>` in order to add elements, then you can transform to an array (if truly needed) via `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToArray();
```

Comment: I was writing while @Anthony-Pegram posted! :(

Comment: This is not array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it in a for loop as follows, calling ToString on the int 'i'

```
private string[] _myArray = new string[1000];

for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
  _myArray[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private readonly string[] _myArray = new string[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < _myArray.Length; i++)
    _myArray[i] = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is method that will generate array of string from 'from' to 'to' inclusive.

```
private string[] GetNumbers(int from, int to)
{
  int size = to - from + 1;
  string[] result = new string[size];
  int number = from;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = number.ToString();
    number++;
  }
  return result;
}

string[] numbers = GetNumbers(1, 1000); // to get what You want
```